# How does python interpreter know where to find sys module when modules are imported?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how python interpreter imports modules. When a module is imported the interpreter searches the paths in the sys.path.I don't understand how the interpreter imports sys module inherently and where does it find the sys module ? If the interpreter has sys module inherently, why do we have to import sys module to use the functions and variables of that module?

```
import math
```

For example, when we import math package, it is checked in the sys.path diectories but how does it know where sys.path actually is?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys` module is a *way* to access python internals, like size of objects, module load paths.

> sys.path
>
> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

On startup, python reads the `PYTHONPATH` env. variable, adds some other built-in paths, and runs your module. When you use `import`, it just looks the module up in the internal path list.

When you import `sys` and you change `path`, it *reflects* in the python internal path. But it's just an API. Had they created a `add_path` (and `remove_path`, `get_path`....) method(s) instead that would have made things less magical, but also less natural.

The underlying mechanism is active even when you're not using it. `sys.path` is a python-level API so everyone understands how to change the configuration, but python doesn't need the `sys` package to operate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also would like to know how Python reads the paths if not from the sys.path API

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says, there's a bunch of default paths:

- the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
- `$prefix/lib/pythonX.Y` on Unix-likes, where `$prefix` is basically "where the binary is located" - so by default it's `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y`, but it could also be `virtualenv/lib/pythonX.Y`. There's also `$execprefix`, but that is usually the same as `$prefix`

Importantly, *in addition* to this, there is a couple of built-in modules. `sys` is one of them. When you write `import sys`, Python will first look into the list of built-ins, and if it finds it, it will not open any files, just do the import.

And when you import other modules, that are not built-in, python will internally look into `sys.path` to find them. For instance, one of the first things python does is `import site`, which it finds on `sys.path`. And this file has instructions to add other import locations: the `site-packages` directory, your home directory paths, possibly a bunch of other places.

So yes, the `sys` module is one of those that are "inherently" in the interpreter.

Why do you have to import it then?

Well, basically because it is a module, and you must always import a module to use it. In a way it's just a formality - you could save a little memory by not importing it (the memory that represents "`sys` exists in your program", even though the actual *code* of the sys module is loaded anyway), but this is not really important.

But the python development team made a decision that modules are never imported automatically, so when you want to use it, you have to ask for it explicitly. This also means that by default, the word "sys" is free for you to use, e.g., as a variable or a function name - and it's always better to leave as many names free for the programmer as possible.